# Indexing tensor with another tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor `xi` of shape `(?, 20, 10)` and another tensor `y_data` of shape `(?, 20, 1)`. I want to use the `y_data` tensor to "index" the `xi` tensor in order to do something like `tf.exp(xi[y_data] - tf.log(tf.reduce_sum(xi, axis=2))`.

E.g. `tf.exp(xi[:, :, 4] - tf.log(tf.reduce_sum(xi, axis=2)))` results in a tensor of shape `(?, 20)`. I just want to get the index, here 4, out ot another tensor.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would use a loop on the possible values for `y_data` which I will assume go from 0 to 9.

```py
result = tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_data), tf.float32)
for i in range(10):
    result = tf.where(tf.equal(y_data, i), tf.exp(xi[:, :, i:i+1]), result)
result = tf.reshape(result, [-1, 20])
result -= tf.log(tf.reduce_sum(xi, axis=2))
```

Probably not the most efficient but that's the only way I could think of.

Comment: Thank you, your answer made me think of another way to solve it. I was able to get `y_data` as one-hot tensor of shape `(?, 20, 10)`. This way the indexing could be done by multiplication and reduction: `tf.reduce_sum(xi * y_data, axis=2)`.